Other ways of using XmlMapper without registerKotlinModule()
I am now experiencing NoSuchMethodError when using the registerKotlinModule() with the recent update on the jackson-module-kotlin at 2.17.1.
I have two instances of using the registerKotlinModule().

ObjectMapper.registerKotlinModule() - I have resolved this by using the code below, but I haven't tested if the code still works but the no more NoSuchMethodError encountered.

val mapper = jsonMapper { addModule(kotlinModule()) }

XmlMapper.registerKotlinModule() - can't seem to find other samples on how to use XmlMapper.

Are there any ways I can use XmlMapper without using registerKotlinModule()?

Try to import this package as well
implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.17.1"
